# Window that does not close

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt5

I created a small Database with sqlite3 and QTableWidget from PyQt5. Records can be added, edited and deleted. When I want to delete a Record, I select it in the QTableWidget and click on the 'Delete' button, after that it displays another Window with the Record and the two buttons 'Ok' and 'Cancel'.
Clicking on 'Ok' deletes the Record from the Database and then with the self.close() instruction the Window should also close, but it doesn't close it and I don't understand the reason. Even if you want to close the Window with the mouse by clicking on the closing X icon, you can't do it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QPushButton,QDialog,QHBoxLayout,QVBoxLayout,QGridLayout,QLabel,QWidget,QLineEdit,QDialogButtonBox,QTableWidget,QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,QPoint,QPointF,QRect,QDateTime,QDate,QTime
import sqlite3
import datetime
import ctypes as ct
import itertools
import re

class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        title = "SQlite3 embeded in QTableWidget";left=100;top=100;width=1200;height=800
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setGeometry(left,top,width,height)

        self.libswiss = ct.CDLL("/usr/lib/libswe.so")
        self.libswiss.swe_set_ephe_path.argtypes = [ct.c_wchar_p]
        self.libswiss.swe_set_ephe_path.restype = None
        path = "/usr/share/ephe"
        self.libswiss.swe_set_ephe_path(path)
        self.libswiss.swe_julday.argtypes = [ct.c_int,ct.c_int,ct.c_int,ct.c_double,ct.c_int]
        self.libswiss.swe_julday.restype = ct.c_double
        self.libswiss.swe_revjul.argtypes = [ct.c_double,ct.c_int,ct.POINTER(ct.c_int),ct.POINTER(ct.c_int),ct.POINTER(ct.c_int),ct.POINTER(ct.c_double)]
        self.libswiss.swe_revjul.restype = None

        self.CreaPulsanteDatabase()
        self.show()

    def CreaPulsanteDatabase(self):
        button = QPushButton("Database", self)
        button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30,100,200,80))
        button.clicked.connect(self.Database)

    def Database(self):
        self.d = DialogDatabase()
        self.d.Crea_FinestraDatabase(1160,700)
        self.d.Crea_Oggetti()
        self.d.Crea_TableWidget_Persone()
        self.d.Crea_Layout(table)
        self.d.Apri_Database_Persone()
        self.d.LoadDatabase_Persone()

    def closeEvent(self,event):
        self.libswiss.swe_close.argtypes = None
        self.libswiss.swe_close.restype = None
        self.libswiss.swe_close()

    def strData2GiornoGiuliano(self,strdata):
        pattern = "^\d+"
        result = re.findall(pattern,strdata)
        giorno = int(result[0])
        pattern = "/(.*?)/"
        result = re.findall(pattern,strdata)
        mese = int(result[0])
        pattern = "\d\d\d\d$"
        result = re.findall(pattern,strdata)
        anno = int(result[0])
        oraUT=0.0;gregflag=1
        GiornoGiuliano = self.libswiss.swe_julday(anno,mese,giorno,oraUT,gregflag)
        return(GiornoGiuliano)


class DialogDatabase(QDialog):

    def Crea_FinestraDatabase(self,width,height):
        title = "Database";left=600;top=360
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setGeometry(left,top,width,height)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color:lightyellow')
        self.iter = itertools.cycle([" ASC"," DESC"])
        self.show()

    def Apri_Database_Persone(self):
        global conn,curs
        conn = sqlite3.connect('Persone.db')
        curs = conn.cursor()
        curs.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Persone (Cognome TEXT, Nome TEXT, Data REAL, Ora TEXT, Fuso TEXT, Località TEXT, Long TEXT, Lat TEXT, Professione TEXT)')

    def LoadDatabase_Persone(self):
        while (table.rowCount() > 0):
            table.removeRow(0)
        w = Window()
        res = curs.execute('SELECT * FROM Persone')
        for row_index, row_data in enumerate(res):
            table.insertRow(row_index)
            for colm_index, colm_data in enumerate(row_data):
                if colm_index == 2:
                    anno=ct.c_int(0);mese=ct.c_int(0);giorno=ct.c_int(0);oraUT=ct.c_double(0.0)
                    w.libswiss.swe_revjul(colm_data,1,anno,mese,giorno,oraUT)
                    strdata = str(giorno.value) + "/" + str(mese.value) + "/" + str(anno.value)
                    table.setItem(row_index,colm_index,QTableWidgetItem(strdata))
                else:
                    table.setItem(row_index,colm_index,QTableWidgetItem(str(colm_data)))

    def Crea_Oggetti(self):
        self.btnEdit = QPushButton("Edit",self)
        self.btnEdit.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.btnEdit.clicked.connect(self.click_Edit)
        self.btnDelete = QPushButton("Delete",self)
        self.btnDelete.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.btnDelete.clicked.connect(self.click_Delete)
        self.btnAdd = QPushButton("Add",self)
        self.btnAdd.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.btnAdd.clicked.connect(self.click_Add)

    def Crea_TableWidget_Persone(self):
        global table
        table = QTableWidget(self)
        table.setRowCount(200)
        table.setColumnCount(9)
        table.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(203,255,203)")
        self.HeaderPersone = ["Cognome","Nome","Data","Ora","Fuso","Località","Long","Lat","Professione"]
        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self.HeaderPersone)
        table.setSortingEnabled(0)

    def Crea_Layout(self,TT):
        hbox1 = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox1.addStretch(1)
        hbox1.addWidget(self.btnEdit)
        hbox1.addWidget(self.btnDelete)
        hbox1.addWidget(self.btnAdd)
        vbox3 = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox3.addLayout(hbox1)
        vbox3.addWidget(TT)
        self.setLayout(vbox3)

    def click_Edit(self):
        pass

    def click_Delete(self):
        res = curs.execute('SELECT * FROM Persone')
        for row in enumerate(res):
            if row[0] == table.currentRow():
                dati = row[1]
                self.Cognome=dati[0];self.Nome=dati[1];self.Data=dati[2];self.Ora=dati[3];self.Fuso=dati[4];self.Località=dati[5];self.Long=dati[6];self.Lat=dati[7];self.Professione=dati[8]
        self.da = Delete_Persone()
        self.da.Crea_FinestraDeletePersone(1160)
        self.da.Crea_OggettieLayoutDeletePersone(self.Cognome,self.Nome,self.Data,self.Ora,self.Fuso,self.Località,self.Long,self.Lat,self.Professione)  # Crea gli Oggetti ed il Layout di Delete Persone, poi se premi Pulsante Ok

    def click_Add(self):
        self.a = Add_Persone()
        self.a.Crea_FinestraAddPersone(1160)
        self.a.Crea_OggettieLayoutAddPersone()


class Add_Persone(DialogDatabase):

    def Crea_FinestraAddPersone(self,width):
        title = "Aggiungi un Record al Database Persone";left=600;top=1120;height=80
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setGeometry(left,top,width,height)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color:white')
        self.show()

    def Crea_OggettieLayoutAddPersone(self):
        Cognomelabel = QLabel("Cognome",self)
        Nomelabel = QLabel("Nome",self)
        Datalabel = QLabel("Data",self)
        Oralabel = QLabel("Ora",self)
        Fusolabel = QLabel("Fuso",self)
        Localitàlabel = QLabel("Località",self)
        Longlabel = QLabel("Long",self)
        Latlabel = QLabel("Lat",self)
        Professionelabel = QLabel("Professione",self)
        self.CognomelineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.CognomelineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.pressInsert)
        self.NomelineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.NomelineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.pressInsert)
        self.DatalineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.DatalineEdit.setToolTip("DD/MM/YYYY")
        self.DatalineEdit.setStyleSheet('QToolTip {font-size:9.4pt;background-color:black; color:white; border:black solid 1px}')
        self.DatalineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.pressInsert)
        self.OralineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.OralineEdit.setToolTip("HH:MM")
        self.OralineEdit.setStyleSheet('QToolTip {font-size:9.4pt;background-color:black; color:white; border:black solid 1px}')
        self.OralineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.pressInsert)
        self.FusolineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.FusolineEdit.setToolTip("se Est metti segno Negativo, per es. -2.0")
        self.FusolineEdit.setStyleSheet('QToolTip {font-size:9.4pt;background-color:black; color:white; border:black solid 1px}')
        self.FusolineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.pressInsert)
        self.LocalitàlineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.LocalitàlineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.pressInsert)
        self.LonglineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.LonglineEdit.setToolTip("per es. 12E36 (12 gradi e 36 minuti Est)\nper es. 118W52 (118 gradi e 52 minuti Ovest)")
        self.LonglineEdit.setStyleSheet('QToolTip {font-size:9.4pt;background-color:black; color:white; border:black solid 1px}')
        self.LonglineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.pressInsert)
        self.LatlineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.LatlineEdit.setToolTip("per es. 42N03 (42 gradi e 3 minuti Nord)\nper es. 26S47 (26 gradi e 47 minuti Sud)")
        self.LatlineEdit.setStyleSheet('QToolTip {font-size:9.4pt;background-color:black; color:white; border:black solid 1px}')
        self.LatlineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.pressInsert)
        self.ProfessionelineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.ProfessionelineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.pressInsert)
        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(Cognomelabel,0,0,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.CognomelineEdit,1,0)
        grid.addWidget(Nomelabel,0,1,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.NomelineEdit,1,1)
        grid.addWidget(Datalabel,0,2,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.DatalineEdit,1,2)
        grid.addWidget(Oralabel,0,3,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.OralineEdit,1,3)
        grid.addWidget(Fusolabel,0,4,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.FusolineEdit,1,4)
        grid.addWidget(Localitàlabel,0,5,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.LocalitàlineEdit,1,5)
        grid.addWidget(Longlabel,0,6,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.LonglineEdit,1,6)
        grid.addWidget(Latlabel,0,7,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.LatlineEdit,1,7)
        grid.addWidget(Professionelabel,0,8,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.ProfessionelineEdit,1,8)
        self.setLayout(grid)

    def pressInsert(self):
        w = Window()
        Cognome = self.CognomelineEdit.text()
        Nome = self.NomelineEdit.text()
        GiornoGiuliano = w.strData2GiornoGiuliano(self.DatalineEdit.text())
        Ora = self.OralineEdit.text()
        Fuso = self.FusolineEdit.text()
        Località = self.LocalitàlineEdit.text()
        Long = self.LonglineEdit.text()
        Lat = self.LatlineEdit.text()
        Professione = self.ProfessionelineEdit.text()
        curs.execute('INSERT INTO Persone VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',(Cognome,Nome,GiornoGiuliano,Ora,Fuso,Località,Long,Lat,Professione))
        conn.commit()
        self.CognomelineEdit.setText("");self.NomelineEdit.setText("");self.DatalineEdit.setText("");self.OralineEdit.setText("");self.FusolineEdit.setText("");self.LocalitàlineEdit.setText("");self.LonglineEdit.setText("");self.LatlineEdit.setText("");self.ProfessionelineEdit.setText("")
        self.CognomelineEdit.setFocus()
        self.d2 = DialogDatabase()
        self.d2.LoadDatabase_Persone()


class Delete_Persone(DialogDatabase):

    def Crea_FinestraDeletePersone(self,width):
        title = "Elimina il Record dal Database Persone";left=600;top=1120;height=80
        self.setWindowTitle(title)
        self.setGeometry(left,top,width,height)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color:white')
        self.show()

    def Crea_OggettieLayoutDeletePersone(self,Cognome,Nome,Data,Ora,Fuso,Località,Long,Lat,Professione):
        self.Cognome=Cognome;self.Nome=Nome;self.Data=Data;self.Ora=Ora;self.Fuso=Fuso;self.Località=Località;self.Long=Long;self.Lat=Lat;self.Professione=Professione
        anno=ct.c_int(0);mese=ct.c_int(0);giorno=ct.c_int(0);oraUT=ct.c_double(0.0)
        w = Window()
        w.libswiss.swe_revjul(Data,1,anno,mese,giorno,oraUT)
        strdata = str(giorno.value) + "/" + str(mese.value) + "/" + str(anno.value)
        Cognomelabel = QLabel("Cognome",self)
        Nomelabel = QLabel("Nome",self)
        Datalabel = QLabel("Data",self)
        Oralabel = QLabel("Ora",self)
        Fusolabel = QLabel("Fuso",self)
        Localitàlabel = QLabel("Località",self)
        Longlabel = QLabel("Long",self)
        Latlabel = QLabel("Lat",self)
        Professionelabel = QLabel("Professione",self)
        self.CognomelineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.CognomelineEdit.setText(Cognome)
        self.CognomelineEdit.setReadOnly(1)
        self.NomelineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.NomelineEdit.setText(Nome)
        self.NomelineEdit.setReadOnly(1)
        self.DatalineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.DatalineEdit.setText(strdata)
        self.DatalineEdit.setReadOnly(1)
        self.OralineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.OralineEdit.setText(Ora)
        self.OralineEdit.setReadOnly(1)
        self.FusolineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.FusolineEdit.setText(Fuso)
        self.FusolineEdit.setReadOnly(1)
        self.LocalitàlineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.LocalitàlineEdit.setText(Località)
        self.LocalitàlineEdit.setReadOnly(1)
        self.LonglineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.LonglineEdit.setText(Long)
        self.LonglineEdit.setReadOnly(1)
        self.LatlineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.LatlineEdit.setText(Lat)
        self.LatlineEdit.setReadOnly(1)
        self.ProfessionelineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.ProfessionelineEdit.setText(Professione)
        self.ProfessionelineEdit.setReadOnly(1)
        self.buttonbox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        self.buttonbox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.buttonbox.setStyleSheet('color:blue;font:bold')
        self.buttonbox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.buttonbox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(Cognomelabel,0,0,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.CognomelineEdit,1,0)
        grid.addWidget(Nomelabel,0,1,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.NomelineEdit,1,1)
        grid.addWidget(Datalabel,0,2,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.DatalineEdit,1,2)
        grid.addWidget(Oralabel,0,3,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.OralineEdit,1,3)
        grid.addWidget(Fusolabel,0,4,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.FusolineEdit,1,4)
        grid.addWidget(Localitàlabel,0,5,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.LocalitàlineEdit,1,5)
        grid.addWidget(Longlabel,0,6,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.LonglineEdit,1,6)
        grid.addWidget(Latlabel,0,7,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.LatlineEdit,1,7)
        grid.addWidget(Professionelabel,0,8,QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid.addWidget(self.ProfessionelineEdit,1,8)
        grid.addWidget(self.buttonbox,2,8)
        self.setLayout(grid)

    def accept(self):
        curs.execute('DELETE FROM Persone WHERE Cognome=? AND Nome=? AND Data=? AND Ora=? AND Fuso=? AND Località=? AND Long=? AND Lat=? AND Professione=?',(self.Cognome,self.Nome,self.Data,self.Ora,self.Fuso,self.Località,self.Long,self.Lat,self.Professione))
        conn.commit()
        self.d3 = DialogDatabase()
        self.d3.LoadDatabase_Persone()
        self.close()

    def reject(self):
        self.close()


class Edit_Persone(DialogDatabase):
    pass


App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

Comment: Note I get an error trying to run this within libswiss so cannot lend you hand sorry.

Comment: I can also upload this library, but I don't know how and where.

Comment: Can you create a functional version of your program that does not use that library and still has the same issue.  I often do this when I have an issue I need help with look at my program and strip it down to its bare essentials and then submit that.

Comment: Jensen, thanks. I wanted to point out that, in all three cases, that is, during the insertion of the Record, the modification and the cancellation, this library is used, but only after the deletion of the record it is not possible to close the Window. It could be some problems related to the two buttons 'Ok' and 'Cancel' because only the 'Delete'-Window has these two buttons.

Comment: Okay sorry did not quite follow you on that -- but again -- see if you can create a functional version of your program that does not use that library if you do not want to remove the calls then create internal function stubs that return the "expected data or does the expected action"

Comment: For instance take this function >> GiornoGiuliano = self.libswiss.swe_julday(anno,mese,giorno,oraUT,gregflag)  << make a local version of it that excepts all those parameters and then just returns what you expect to get back from it (aka whatever would get placed into GiornoGiuliano --- aka your are building a functional test using static or semi-static data if that makes any sense

Comment: So, I completely deleted the library and entered a static value in the 'Data' field, but the problem persists, so I also tried to remove the two buttons 'Ok' and 'Cancel' (from QDialogButtonBox), but nothing to do, the Window does not close ......... and then I thought that for the cancellation of the Record I could also use the QMessageBox and in fact everything works perfectly with this. Strange ..... very very strange.